# How many records does Yajra display?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I want to use Yajra DataTables to display user data. There are more than 100000 registered users on my website. I want to know does Yajra supports data of 100000 users or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yajra DataTables is a package that handles the server-side works of DataTables using Laravel.

Data will be fetched using ajax request & it will be in pagination format. so no issue if users are 100000 or more than this.

You can set the row limit per page.